# SELECT All that are not in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've inherited a less-than-ideal table structure, and I'm trying to improve it as much as I can without tearing down and rebuilding.  There's currently at least two levels of data for everything, the legacy data and the marketing override data.  I'm trying to find all the records within the legacy data that don't yet have a marketing override.

So far, this is what I have:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  old.STYLE_NBR, old.COLOR_NBR 
FROM 
  LEGACY_PRODUCT_TABLE old
INNER JOIN 
  MARKETING_PRODUCT_TABLE new
ON old.STYLE_NBR <> new.style_number AND old.COLOR_NBR <> new.colour_number
```

This seems to work, but it takes a few minutes to run.  If at all possible, I'd like a more efficient way of doing this.

Other info:

- There are about 60,000 records in the legacy table
- There are about 7,000 in the marketing table
- Both `STYLE_NBR` and `COLOR_NBR` are char(5) and, when combined, make a unique ID.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be using a LEFT OUTER JOIN and change your lookup

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  old.STYLE_NBR, old.COLOR_NBR 
FROM 
  LEGACY_PRODUCT_TABLE old
  LEFT OUTER JOIN MARKETING_PRODUCT_TABLE new
    ON (old.STYLE_NBR + old.COLOR_NBR) = (new.style_number + new.Colour_number)
WHERE (new.style_number + new.Colour_number) IS NULL
```

Answer (score 4):

What you currently have is incorrect because it will return a row for every row that *doesn't* match, so potentially 6999 rows in the result per row in the legacy table if there is marketing override, or 7000 if there isn't. the distinct will then discard the duplicates, but the result will be wrong because even if there is a marketing matching row, the non-matching ones will make sure the result set will include the ones where there is no row.

Try this instead:

```
select distinct style_nbr, color_nbr
 from legacy_product_table L
where not exists
(
   select * from marketing_product_table m
   where m.style_nbr = L.style_nbr and m.color_nbr = L.color_nbr
)
```

Make sure the product table has an index on (style_nbr,color_nbr).

Comment: I prefer the left join method, but I like the way you explained why the orginal was incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Are the join fields indexed? That should speed things up considerably. Make sure old.STYLE_NBR, old.COLOR_NBR, new.style_number, and new.color_number are indexed.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will be faster, but it may be worth a try.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  old.STYLE_NBR, old.COLOR_NBR 
FROM 
  LEGACY_PRODUCT_TABLE old
WHERE old.STYLE_NBR, old.COLOR_NBR 
NOT IN 
(
    SELECT old.STYLE_NBR, old.COLOR_NBR 
    FROM LEGACY_PRODUCT_TABLE old
    INNER JOIN 
        MARKETING_PRODUCT_TABLE new
        ON 
            old.STYLE_NBR == new.style_number AND old.COLOR_NBR == new.colour_number
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
    old.* 
FROM 
    LEGACY_PRODUCT_TABLE old 
LEFT JOIN
    MARKETING_PRODUCT_TABLE new 
ON 
    new.style_number=old.STYLE_NBR AND 
    new.colour_number=old.COLOR_NBR 
WHERE 
    new.style_number IS NULL;
```

Stands a better chance of using the indexes which you presumably have on the four columns in question.

Answer (score 1):

Some options to try are:

```
SELECT
    old.STYLE_NBR,
    old.COLOR_NBR
FROM  
    LEGACY_PRODUCT_TABLE old
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    MARKETING_PRODUCT_TABLE new
ON
    old.STYLE_NBR = new.style_number
AND
    old.COLOR_NBR = new.colour_number
WHERE
    new.style_number IS NULL



SELECT
    old.STYLE_NBR,
    old.COLOR_NBR
FROM  
    LEGACY_PRODUCT_TABLE old
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        MARKETING_PRODUCT_TABLE new
    WHERE
        old.STYLE_NBR = new.style_number
    AND
        old.COLOR_NBR = new.colour_number
)
```

EDIT: The key thing with both of these is that you are joining using = rather than <>.

Answer (score 0):

What about NOT EXISTS?

```
SELECT DISTINCT old.STYLE_NBR, old.COLOR_NBR 
FROM LEGACY_PRODUCT_TABLE old
WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT 1 FROM MARKETING_PRODUCT_TABLE new 
    WHERE old.STYLE_NBR = new.style_number 
      AND old.COLOR_NBR = new.colour_number)
```

Answer (score 0):

-- What about EXCEPT? (if this is SQL Server 2005 or 2008)
select old.Style_NBR, Old.Color_NBR
except
select new.Style_NBR, new.Color_NBR

-- try the code below in mssql 2008

declare @Old    table(
    Color_Nbr   tinyint,
    Style_Nbr   tinyint
)

declare @New    table (
    Color_Nbr   tinyint,
    Style_Nbr   tinyint
)

insert into @Old 
values  (1,1),
        (2,2),
        (3,3),
        (4,4)

insert into @New
values  (1,1),
        (2,2),
        (3,3),
        (5,5)

select  o.Color_Nbr,
    o.Style_Nbr
from @Old o

except

select  n.Color_Nbr,
    n.Style_Nbr
from @New n